# How to pronounce "×" in "12 × 3 mm²"?

Tags: numbers, mathematics, symbols

I have this expression:

> 12 × 3 mm².

I guess that it should not be pronounced as "twelve multiplied by three millimeters squared". I've tried to google it already but it seemed to be difficult because of my lack of proficiency in searching keywords.

**Note** that *12 x 3* should be pronounced in the same way as shape e.g. 4x2 rectangle (rectangle with width = 4 and height = 2).

Comment: I think that should be 12mm x 3mm.

Comment: In my (SE UK) vernacular, I'd normally enunciate the ***x*** as ***by*** (same vowel as in ***high***), but for more common dimensions such as ***2 by 4** (inches)*, I'd normally reduce/shorten the vowel sound to that of, say, ***bit***.  That reduced enunciation explains many written instances of [***four be two***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22four+be+two%22)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth In physics, people prefer to this form, just to show an explicit unit.

Comment: Nobody prefers to any form. And I'm basically a scientist, and have never met the usage you say is preferred. There are no Google hits for "2 by 1 square inches", "2 by 1 square centimetres", or "2 by 1 square imillimetres", and I suspect there won't be any if we substitute cm^2 etc. I'll ask the ex-coordinator of science teaching in our region next time I see him.

Comment: I don't really understand the purpose of "squared" in this context. We're already talking about a *two-dimensional* measurement anyway, so it just comes across to me as a confusing additional element (maybe having something to do with ***cubic*** measures, or maybe it's talking about twelve separate items with area 3 square mm, or 3mm squares equaling ***9*** square mm each).

Comment: It is also common in US English to pronounce the × symbol "**times**".

Comment: @EdwinAshworth That's not really true. In some people's eyes, `mm` might just means "unit" but in physicists' eyes, they see "`[length]`" and for `mm^2` they see "`[length]^2`". Yes, it shows an explicit physical meaning. When you say `12 mm x 3 mm` to physicist, he might think that you are talking about two things but talk `12 x 3 mm^2` he knows you exactly talk about 2 dimensional plane.

Comment: Same as `23 [m]/7 [s]`, physicists prefer to `23/7 [m/s]` because [m/s] tells you that it is a "velocity". Imagine that if you don't group units into any meaningful forms (in sense of physics), so, you can not tell exactly what is it. This is a big trouble, especially in complicated calculation e.g. you write ten separated units in equation in stead of group them into 2 meaningful physical unit.

Comment: I think EdwinAshworth is saying that '36 mm^2' makes sense when describing an area, and '12mm x 3mm' makes sense when describing a shape, but the partially complete '12 x 3 mm^2' looks odd; even though (12x3)mm^2 = 12x(3mm^2).

Comment: You are confusing two ideas. For lengths, the 'x' or 'by' construction is commonly used (eg by joiners) to specify the relevant dimensions (eg 6 foot of 2" by 3", usually shortened to 6 foot of 2-bi-3). Scientists would say 36 mm^2. rather than 12 x 3 mm^2. If this is being written as a part of a calculation, 'x' reads as 'times'.

Comment: As part of a calculation, it should be pronounced as "twelve times/multiplied by three ... millimeters squared", where the ellipsis shows a pause to indicate that (12 x 3) is cohesive.

Comment: OK, no one should change `12 x 3 mm^2` into any other forms. I will mention here "12 means width", "3 means height" and "mm^2" means "two dimensional plane". `x` should be pronounced in the same way as `x` in context of shape e.g. "2(width) x 4(height) square".

Comment: Given your recent comment, "by" is correct. Much like a "[two by four](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2%C3%974)" is an (approximately) two-inch by four-inch piece of lumber of varying length.

Comment: "12 × 3" is "twelve times three" or "twelve by three", depending on whether you're talking about multiplication or specifying x-y dimensions.  The "mm²" is "square millimeters" if the first expression is multiplication, nonsensical if it is dimensions -- in that case it should just be "mm".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

'by' as in 12 by 3 square millimeters

Comment: Or 12 by 3 millimeters squared. Either is acceptable.

Comment: @Catija I agree, either pronunciation of the units is acceptable.

Answer (score 3):

If it is describing the size of a single rectangular shape, then ***by*** is the correct pronunciation.

If it is describing a number of squares, then you can leave it silent.

> 12 3 millimeter squares.

If it is a scalar multiplied to a square unit in a mathematical calculation, then ***times*** can be used.

> 12 *times* 3 mm<sup>2</sup>

Comment: The answer was authored before the OP added the additional note.